# Trimming Special Characters in Apache Spark in java

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to remove all the special characters like space (" "), comma (","), semicolon (";"), colon (":"), period ("."), apostrophe (“’”), quotation marks (“””), exclamation (“!”), question mark (“?”), and brackets ("[", “{”, “(”, “<”,"]", “)”, “}”,”>” ). Can someone guide me for this?

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object count {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 1) {
      System.err.println("Usage: HdfsWordCount <directory>")
      System.exit(1)
    }
 
    //StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels()
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HdfsWordCount").setMaster("local")
    // Create the context
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
 
    // Create the FileInputDStream on the directory and use the
    // stream to count words in new files created
    val lines = ssc.textFileStream(args(0))
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
    wordCounts.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replaceAll should help here.

```
val wordCounts = lines.flatMap(line => line.split(\"\\\W+\")).map(_.replaceAll(\"[{~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),_,=,-,\`,:,',?,/,<,>,.}]\", \"\").trim.toLowerCase).filter(word => !word.isEmpty && word.matches(\"[A-Za-z]+\")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

alphanumeric would also be counted

Comment: I think it shows come syntax error like invalid escape character